# Which of these two queries is more efficient or run best?

Tags: sql

query 1

```
SELECT m.Name, p.Name, p.Price
    FROM Manufacturers m INNER JOIN Products p
        ON m.Code = p.Manufacturer
WHERE p.Price IN (SELECT MAX(pp.Price) FROM Products pp GROUP BY pp.Manufacturer);
```

query 2

```
  select m.Name as ManufName, p.Name as ProductName, p.Price as ProductPrice
    from Manufacturers m inner join Products p
      on m.Code = p.Manufacturer
        where p.Price =   (select max(sub_p.Price)
                                  from Products sub_p
                                    where m.Code = sub_p.Manufacturer);
```

Which one should take less time?

Comment: What's preventing you from running and seeing which takes less time?

Comment: These queries are not equivalent. If they were, the answer would depend on which SQL engine you're using.

Comment: please, see the comment to Troy's answer, I was running these queries on a small set of data. I understand it would depend on the database engine and table configuration (index...) even if these two queries are the same like they use the same columns but a simple broad explanation is just what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Size of the tables, indices, etc. Try them both and compare.

However, knowing nothing of your database, I will wager a guess that query 1 should perform better.  Query 2 has a [correlated sub query](http://www.sqlservice.se/sql-server-performance-death-by-correlated-subqueries/) and that will cause the optimizer to use a nested loop.

Comment: that was a general training question for theory, thanks